# The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute a `xp_cmdshell` command to change the ip of the SQL Server server.

The `EXEC` command is as follows:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.XXX.XXX 255.255.255.0 192.168.XXX.XXX'
```

The IP is X'ed for security reasons.

The `netsh` command executes successfully under command console, but the SQL Server query generates the following error:

> The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).

The full query code is:

```
USE MASTER;
GO

CREATE LOGIN [backup-dt\itm] FROM WINDOWS;

EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'backup-dt\itm','Letmein@2018'

--Create the database role and assign rights to the role
CREATE ROLE [CmdShell_Executor] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GRANT EXEC ON xp_cmdshell TO [CmdShell_Executor]

--Then once done create users and assign to CmdShell_Executor
CREATE USER [Backup-dt\CmdShellExec] FROM LOGIN [Backup-dt\CmdShellExec];
EXEC sp_addrolemember [CmdShell_Executor],[Backup-dt\CmdShellExec];

grant execute on xp_cmdshell to [backup-dt\itm]
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.XXX.XXX 255.255.255.0 192.168.XXX.XXX'
```

Any idea how can I elevate the access to administrator and make this command execute successfully?

Thanks,

Comment: Why is your SQL Server instance changing the host computer's IP address in the first place? This sounds like a very convoluted "solution" to something that should rarely happen in the first place.

Comment: This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) under permissions section has some info

Comment: How exactly do you run this query?

Comment: To start with, this code is going to be a part of another code which checks for another server's availability. If the other server fails for some reason, this server with change its IP to that server's IP to take over the database connectivity.

Comment: I am executing this in the query window.

Comment: You are hitting UAC and from `xp_cmdshell` there is no way to create that shell in a "run as administrator" privilege. You could by running it under PowerShell process but would take extra lines of code. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/

Comment: @ShawnMelton but this is in powershell. Isn't there a way to execute such a command in MS SQL server? I tried running a .bat file through EXEC as well but it didn't work.

Comment: @BadihBarakat it sounds like you're attempting to create your own version of a Failover Clustered Instance or Availability Group. Make sure that there aren't already solutions to your business requirement before hacking something together yourself.

Comment: @BadihBarakat your code does not show anywhere that you are executing PowerShell. (1) `netsh` is not a PowerShell command. (2) `xp_cmdshell` starts a cmd.exe shell, not PowerShell.exe. So you are not executing anything in or with PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

> > this code is going to be a part of another code which checks for another server's availability. If the other server fails for some reason, this server with change its IP to that server's IP to take over the database connectivity

So Windows has a feature for this in Windows [Failover Clustering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/failover-clustering-overview).  It will monitor the health of multiple instances, and fail over resources (including IP addresses) to healthy nodes.

You can create a cluster just to manage a floating IP address, and have SQL Server instances running on both nodes.  But that's only a partial solution, as the SQL Servers may both actually be online in case of a network issue, and you'll have a split brain.

SQL Server integrates with Windows Failover Clustering to provide two complete, and widely-used HA solutions.  [Failover Cluster Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/always-on-failover-cluster-instances-sql-server), which use shared (or replicated) storage, and [Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server) (which don't need shared storage).

Comment: I am testing this and will confirm ASAP... :)